# Dumping thread stacks on signal ocaml

Tags: signals, ocaml, stack-trace

I have an OUnit test that doesn't halt and I'd like to be able to get a stacktrace.

I'm compiling with `-g` and I get a stacktrace when a test completes abnormally.

I tried trapping signals, but can't figure out how to dump stacks for live threads

```
let () = begin
  (* Report stacktraces in test failures *)
  Printexc.record_backtrace true;

  (* Exit on Ctrl-C. *)
  let flush_and_abort _ =
    prerr_string "aborted by signal\n";
    (***** What do I do here to dump stacks for live threads? ****)
    flush stderr;
    flush stdout;
    exit ~-1 in
  Sys.set_signal Sys.sigint  (Sys.Signal_handle flush_and_abort);
  Sys.set_signal Sys.sigquit (Sys.Signal_handle flush_and_abort);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think signal handlers are executed in a context where you can get the backtrace. The natural choice would be to use `Printexc.print_backtrace stderr`, but (on my machine at least) it doesn't work.

My advice would be to use runtime profiling instead: compile with `ocamlopt -p` (or `.p.native` ocamlbuild's target), run your program, interrupt it, and use `gprof <executable>` to see the profiling info. It should highlight in which function was most of the time spent, and with visualization tool such as [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) you can get reasonable call graphs. Not optimal, but may still solve your problems.

PS: I think you still need your signal catching routine for profiling to work: if the program is killed instead of interrupting itself it may not spit out the profiling information.